# Воспроизведение музыки на странице

Tags: java, html, ajax

В одном из полей сущности хранится музыкальная композиция (также есть текст и картинка), сущность хранится в базе. Ajax запросом обращаюсь к Spring контролёру, достаю список сущностей из базы и json'ом отправляю на страницу, там прохожу по этому списку, отображаю текст, картинку, а вот с муз.композицией не выходит. В моей реализации каждому объекту отображаемого списка соответствует свой плеер, но это не обязательно, он может быть и один, например вверху страницы, а с помощью jQuery подставлять src соответствующего объекта (так пробовал, результат тот же). В отображаемом на странице списке на долю секунды появляется плеер и исчезает, подскажите, что не так??
Сущность

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long idMessage;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date = new Date();

    private String text;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    @Lob
    private byte[] img;

    private String nameSong;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    @Lob
    private byte[] song;
```

Методы контролёра для загрузки сообщений, а так же поиска в базе изображения и муз.композиции

```
@RequestMapping("/upload/messages")
    public void uploadMessages(Model model,
                               HttpServletResponse response,
                               @ModelAttribute(value = "date") Date date) {

        List<Message> messageList = serviceMessage.findAllMessage(date);// загружаем полный стек сообщений
        if (!messageList.isEmpty()) {
            date = messageList.get(messageList.size() - 1).getDate();
            model.addAttribute("date", date);
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "";
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(messageList);
            response.getWriter().println(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        @RequestMapping("/find/img")
        public ResponseEntity<byte[]> findImg(HttpServletRequest request) {
            long idMessage = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("idMessage"));
            byte[] img = serviceMessage.findImg(idMessage);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(img, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        @RequestMapping("/find/song")
        public ResponseEntity<byte[]> findSong(HttpServletRequest request) {
            long idMessage = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("idMessage"));
            byte[] song = serviceMessage.findSong(idMessage);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.ALL);
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(song, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Разметка html, использую jsp страницу

```
...
    <div id="messageList">
        <%-- Message List... --%>
    </div>
...
```

Код jQuery

```
function UploadMessage() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "upload/messages",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false
        },
        success: SuccessUploadMessage
    })
}

function SuccessUploadMessage(result) {

    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
        var txt = value.text;
        var img = value.img;
        var nameSong = value.nameSong;

        if (txt != null || img != null || nameSong != null) {
            $("#messageList").prepend("<div id='oneMessage'></div>");// предварительно создаём отдельный блок для каждого сообщения

            if (txt != null) {// вставляем текст сообщения
                $("#oneMessage").append("<li id='myText' style='display: none'>" + value.text + "</li>");
                $("#myText").fadeIn(1500);
            }

            if (img != null) {// вставка изображения
                $("#oneMessage").append("<img id='myImg' src='' style='width: 140px; height: 100px; display: none'>");
                $("#myImg").attr("src", "find/img/?idMessage=" + value.idMessage);
                $("#myImg").show(800)
            }

            if (nameSong != null) {// вставляем аудиофайл
                $("#oneMessage").append("<audio id='mySong' controls='controls' src=''></audio>");
                $("#mySong").attr("src", "find/song/?idMessage" + value.idMessage)
            }

            $("#messageList").prepend("<br>")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Покажите код entity.

Comment: `@SergeyGornostaev` Добавил код сущности

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вам понадобиться дополнительный метод контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/song/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public byte[] downloadSong(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Message message = messageService.findById(id);
    return message.getSong();
}
```

Тогда в jsp `<source src="/contexturl/controllerurl/song/${message.id}">`

Comment: Подскажите, как это можно сделать (воспроизвести композицию) на странице методом $.ajax(), т.е. без перезагрузки страницы. Т.к. страница загружается один раз, новые записи появляются в реальном времени и перехватываются на странице через ajax.

Comment: Делаете rest-сервис, JavaScript'ом получаете от него список композиций, отображаете список на странице. При клике на элементе списка, устанавливаете в `source` плеера соответствующий url.

Comment: Именно это я и хотел узнать. Можно подробнее, как в src поместить необходимый путь url?

Comment: Что-то вроде `$('#tracks').on('click', '.track', function(evt) { $('#player > source').prop('src', $(this).data('url')); })`

Comment: Чтобы не столкнутся с проблемами, `byte[]` придётся подвергнуть base64-кодированию. Что увеличит размер передаваемых данных примерно на треть. На стороне клиента нужно будет превратить ответ из json-строки в объект JavaScript-объект, что целиком расположит его в памяти. После чего JavaScript'ом нужно будет получить значение поля, содержащего данные и присвоить это значение атрибуту `src` или тега `audio` или `source`, что засунет эти данные ещё раз в память. Плохая идея.

Comment: Выходит, что оставив как есть, каждый audio будет запросом к контроллеру, а далее в базу. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы запрос от audio к контроллеру происходил только после нажатия кнопки плей?

Comment: Вам ничего не мешает сделать один плеер на странице и JavaScript'ом менять его атрибут src.

Comment: При возврате ResponseEntity содержащего картинку, пишем так `... HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(img, headers, HttpStatus.OK);`. Что указывать для аудиофайла в параметре `MediaType.`?